# ngRepeat on another repeaters value's array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Using **AngularJS**.

Having the following **JSON** piece:

```
"skills": {
"Charisma": {},
"Dexterity": {
  "Sk3": [
    [
      true,
      true,
      true,
      true,
      false
    ],
    44
  ]
}, ...
```

And the following corresponding **HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-info" ng-repeat="(key, value) in character.skills | orderBy:'$index':true">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{key}}">
                        <header>
                            <label>{{key}}</label>
                        </header>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <ul id="{{key}}" class="list-group collapse">
                    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(K, V) in value">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        <label>{{K}}</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> ...
```

**How do i repeat and bind the boolean array to my checkbox inputs?**
*The result would be 5 checkboxes in front of each skill's name, being selected or unselected depending on boolean values.*

I tried something like:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(K, V) in value">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="bool in V[0]" ng-model="V[0]"/>
       <label>{{K}}</label>
</li>
```

But that's a no-go..

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: Just a stab. Does `<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="bool in V[0]" ng-bind="V[0][$index]"/>` work?

Comment: Well firstly there are no checkboxes being repeated at all, so it doesn't show any.. so i can't really tell.

Comment: @Taerus It doesn't show because you have duplicates in array so you need to track items by `$index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to boolean array elements like this in your case:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="bool in V[0] track by $index" ng-model="V[0][$index]" />
```

Note, that since there are duplicated items in array you have to use `track by $index` expression. Also you need to use `ngModel` directive.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/87N6gpGOnLCCpTOvxJo0?p=preview